# Angular universal: flickering and styles

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using angular cli 1.5, angular 5.0 and angular universal.

When using server side rendering, I'm noticing some flicker when the client takes over.

I've already specified { initialNavigation: 'enabled' } when importing routing module.

When could it come from? Also, I tried removing all styles from the server bundle, but it does not help... Is it really needed btw?

Comment: do you use TransferState API?

Comment: @wassertim: Yes, that was indeed the problem, thanks

Comment: @David did you solve the problem? I have same issue but I don't know how to solve it. Server return correct HTML's but client rebuild it again, so I have flickering / blinking..

Comment: @psalkowski: Yes, the transferstate api solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the TransferState API, which prevented  flickering

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState

Thanks @wassertim

Comment: Can you answer this question please ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365849/angular-universal-app-performance-app-bootstrap-listener-flicker

Comment: @Rakeschand I posted a verbose answer for you

Answer (score 0):

In `app.module.ts` add the following to your `imports:` array:

```
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'your-app-id-here'}),
BrowserTransferStateModule
```

In `app.server.module.ts` add the following to your `imports:` array:

```
ServerTransferStateModule
```

Comment: that works in angular 5 not in angular 4, though I have updated my app so it's workng now Thanks